# Request to flickr not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, flickr

I'm trying to make a request to flickr with ultimate failure. Not sure what I'm doing wrong and hope someone can point me in the right direction. I looked up the documentation, the flickr documentation is not really beginner friendly.
here's what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var key = 'myKeyhere';

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key='+myKeyhere+'&user_id=12345&format=jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        sucess: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            } 
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issue. Try the below. I have switched to echo test method of flikr for testing purpose. You need to define callback method ***jsonFlickrApi*** and switch https protocol. Specify format as json in url, else Flickr will return xml data which will tough to handle with jsonp calls.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.test.echo&name=value&api_key='+api key+'&format=json',
                    dataType: 'jsonp'
                });
            function jsonFlickrApi (response) {
              console.log(response);
}
    </script>
```